# ajax callback to insert image if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) answer in an attempt to write good asynchronous js - but I can't quite figure out what's going wrong for me.

I'm using autocomplete to request a specific set of files from the server, but for some datasets these files may not exist (i.e, there may be one, or up to four files). If they do exist, I want to append .html to include them.

The images don't load unless I add

> async: false

to the .ajax call, which makes the callback redundant.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  (function (counter) {
    // define function with the callback argument
    function ajaxTest(callback) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: counter + "_1.jpg",
        success: function (result) {
          callback(counter);
        }
      });
    }
    // call the function
    ajaxTest(function (num) {
      var image_temp = '<div class="thumbnail"> <img class="img-thumbnail" src="'+ num + '_1.jpg" /> Image' + num + '</div>';
      console.log(image_temp); //check readout
      image_html += image_temp;
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Then image_html contains html for only those images that exist.

> $('#outputcontent').html(outer_html +  image_html +  outer_html_end);

Can anyone explain to my misunderstanding here please? Why isn't image_html being populated?

EDIT: 'full' code below. I use jquery autocomplete to pull from the stellar_comp array, then for those with properties that exist (some are blank), html is generated. Within that is the ajax call.

```
$(function () {
 var stellar_comp = [
     {
         value:'X0005-28',
         data: {
             set0: {
                 aperture:'X2105-28',
                 secat:'X025-18',
                 set:'1',
                 run:'r06',
                 continuumFilter:'J',
                 narrowBandFilter:'638/28',
                 numberOfSources:'1',
                 priorityCode:'1'
                    etc... etc ...
        },      
   },
 ];


 $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: stellar_comp,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {


    var path_Value = 'data/' + suggestion.value + '/';
    var outer_html = '<h1>' + suggestion.value + ' </h1> <div class="container">';
    var outer_html_end = '</div>';


    for (var category in suggestion.data) {
        if (suggestion.data.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
            if (suggestion.data[category].aperture) {

                summary_table_contents = '<tr> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].set + '</td> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].run + '</td> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].continuumFilter + '</td> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].narrowBandFilter + '</td> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].numberOfSources + '</td> <td>' + suggestion.data[category].priorityCode + '</td></tr> ';

                summary_table += summary_table_contents;

                var aperturePlot = suggestion.data[category].aperture + '_' + suggestion.data[category].run;
                var seCATPlot = suggestion.data[category].secat + '_Rsub_ss_' + suggestion.data[category].run;
                var aperture_match = suggestion.data[category].aperture_match;


                cog = path_Plots + aperturePlot + '_cog';
                sbprof = path_Plots + aperturePlot + '_sbprof';
                thumb_cog = '';
                thumb_cog_temp = '';
                thumb_sb = '';
                temp='';
                for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    (function (counter) {
                        function some_function(callback) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: cog + counter + "_1.jpg",
                                async: false,
                                success: function (result) {
                                    callback(counter);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        some_function(function (num) {

                            var thumb_cog_temp = '<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> <a class="thumbnail" target="_blank" href="' + cog + num + '_1.jpg"> <img class="img-thumbnail" src="' + cog + num + '_4.jpg" /></a> <div class="caption"><h5>' + suggestion.value + ':S' + num + '</h5></div></div>';
                            var thumb_sb_temp = '<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> <a class="thumbnail" target="_blank" href="' + sbprof + num + '_1.jpg"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="' + sbprof + num + '_4.jpg" /></a><div class="caption"><h5>' + suggestion.value + ':S' + num + ' </h5></div></div>';
                            console.log(num, counter);
                            thumb_cog += thumb_cog_temp;
                            thumb_sb += thumb_sb_temp;
                        });
                    })(i);
                }


                cog_sbprofile_row='<div class="row"><h3>C o G</h3> ' + thumb_cog + '</div><div class="row"><h3>Profiles</h3>  ' + thumb_sb + '</div>';
                console.log(cog_sbprofile_row);
                body_html += aperture_row;
                body_html += seCAT_row;
                body_html += aperture_match_row;
                body_html += pixel_map_row;
                body_html += skyprofile_row;
                body_html += cog_sbprofile_row;
                body_html += '<hr>';
            };
        };
    };
    top_html += summary_table + '</tbody> </table> </div></div> <hr>';

    $('#outputcontent').html(outer_html +  hipass_container + top_html + body_html +  outer_html_end);

     }
 });

});
```

Comment: Do you execute "$('#outputcontent').html(outer_html + image_html + outer_html_end);" after all async task is completed?

Comment: Ah, I don't know - how do I check for this?

Comment: As `Chickenrice` suggests, you have no code shown that would wait for all the async Ajax calls to finish before trying to update the HTML. You need to show the rest of your code to allow for a solution to be provided as your code will need to be reorganized. *P.S. You should never use `async: false`*.

Comment: Q: Is the display order of the images important? Do they need to be sequential (or just in the order loaded)?

Comment: Because the AJAX image loader will load picture asynchronously, you need to make sure that all pictures have been loaded properly before you append them to the container DOM.

Comment: Have added more info. @Chickenrice how do I do that? Definitely sounds  like that's what I've got to do - just unsure how to check.

Comment: Added a much simpler solution below using uniquely numbered/id placeholders.

Comment: Just curious, but why use AJAX to load the images when you could just create an off-screen `Image` element ?

Comment: @Alnitak could you expand on this? I don't know how many images I'll be displaying until I make the ajax call - could be a single image, could be up to four.

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus the "normal" way to pre-load an image is to simply do `var img = new Image(); img.src = url` (with a `.onload` handler if required).  Curious why you use XMLHTTPRequest with all the cross-origin restrictions that imposes.

Comment: simple answer - I don't know any better yet! So how would I do that client-side without first knowing which images existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current problem is due to using the resulting HTML string, before it has been created via multiple asynchronous calls. You need to either defer that operation until *all* loads are completed, or change the situation so it is not dependent on final completion (progressive loading looks busier anyway).

Personally I would simply insert placeholders for the images as you loop and insert each *as they load*. This way the order is retained. You can even do effects (fade etc) on each as they load:

```
var wrapper = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  // Make a placeholder element for each image we expect
  wrapper += '<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb_' + i + '">'

  (function (num) {
    // call the function
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: num + "_1.jpg",
      success: function (result) {
          var image_temp = '<img class="img-thumbnail" src="'+ num + '_1.jpg" /> Image' + num;
          // Insert new image into unique element and fade it in
          $('#thumb_'+num).append(image_temp).fadeIn(); 
      }
    });
  })(i);
}

// Append all placeholders immediately - these will be appended to as each image is loaded
$('#outputcontent').html(outer_html + wrappers + outer_html_end);
```

### Update:

As `Alnitak` points out, the whole exercise is a little pointless as you are ignoring the result returned from the Ajax call anyway, so you might as well drop the Ajax call (which adds no value) and simply build the image elements on the fly *server-side* :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the suggestion of building image elements on the fly - as I said in the original post, there aren't always four images. How will I know whether an image exists and therefore should be displayed without first executing an ajax request?

Comment: I like the idea of fadeIn(), will have a go at this now

Comment: a </div> was needed on the end of wrapper, but I've got this working and I *think* I'm starting to get a grip on closure and scope. Thanks ever so much for your help!

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus: I should have explained more clearly. If the images are on the server, then building the list of images should be done server-side and not on the client. No point making all those Ajax requests for local server files that will simply get pulled down by the browser. Hope all this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the appending after all ajax requests finish their jobs. First define this:

```
var after = function(reqs) {
    var d = $.Deferred(),
        cnt = reqs.length;

    if (!cnt) {
        d.resolve();
    }

    var limit = cnt;  // separate var just in case reqs are synchronous
                      // so it won't mess up the loop

    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        reqs[i].always(function() {
            cnt--;
            if (!cnt) {
                d.resolve();
            }
        });
    }
    return d.promise();
};
```

You can use `$.when` instead of this but if one of the requests results in `404` it won't wait for others. Now:

```
var image_html = "",
    requests = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  (function (counter) {
    // define function with the callback argument
    function ajaxTest(callback) {
      return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: counter + "_1.jpg",
        success: function (result) {
          callback(counter);
        }
      });
    }
    // call the function
    var req = ajaxTest(function (num) {
      var image_temp = '<div class="thumbnail"> <img class="img-thumbnail" src="'+ num + '_1.jpg" /> Image' + num + '</div>';
      console.log(image_temp); //check readout
      image_html += image_temp;
    });

    requests.push(req);  // push the request to the array
  })(i);
}

after(requests).done(function() {
    $('#outputcontent').html(outer_html + image_html + outer_html_end);
});
```

Note that I've added `return $.ajax(...)`.

BTW: what's the point of defining `ajaxTest` function? Just put everything in an anonymous callback.

Read more about deferred objects and promises here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

or just google it.

**EDIT**: if the order is important then you just have to tweak the callback function a bit:

```
var image_html = [];  // array instead of string

// some code...

        var req = ajaxTest(function (num) {
            // ...
            image_html[counter] = image_temp;
        });

// some code...
after(requests).done(function() {
    image_html = image_html.join("");
    $('#outputcontent').html(outer_html + image_html + outer_html_end);
});
```

Comment: You have just described a `promise`-based solution to a newbie *without explanation*. You might want to explain it in some detail.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well, that's quite a big topic. I've added some resources. Hopefuly it will be enough, I don't really want to explain all details.

Comment: Thanks @freakish - looks like I've got another day of reading ahead of me. I think I see how it works.

Comment: The SO has not answered my question, but it is likely the image display order is important, else you could just append each image as they load and forget all this complexity. *If* the order is important your answer will not solve the entire problem. Cheers.

Comment: Though yes, as a newbie, I'll probably be coming back for help tomorrow too. Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: sorry, @TrueBlueAussie the order is important, I do need image1 to sit above image4 (but I don't mind if it loads after it!)

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus: In that case you need to store each result into an array (indexed by the image number) as well as the other changes shown or similar. `image_html += image_temp` will simply result in the load order. The end result is you need to wait for all results and keep the results in order. Then display after all have finished loading.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Even without ordering you can still do it if you want all images to appear at the same time. Anyway I've added ordering.

Comment: That will work, but I find the solution far too complicated for the desired result (it's just an ordered list of images). Have added a simpler alternative using placeholders. Cheers

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie True, however your code works slightely different. As I mentioned: in my case all images appear at the same time. In you case they appear irregularly. So it depends on what OP really wants.

Comment: Yes. I noted those issues. The whole exercise is a waste as the Ajax call result is ignored :)

Comment: Ah, I still don't understand why you say the Ajax call is not needed. If I don't know how many images to display (could be 1 to 4) then surely I need to make a server request to check?